# Javascript multiply algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to learn JavaScript arrays and algorithms and for loops.
I am trying to make a function, that takes an array as a parameter, and has to multiply each number in the array with the next number.
I can't seem to figure out what I am missing.

It just returns the array

```
function xNumbers (arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.lenght-1; i++) {
        var num1 = arr[i]
        var num2 = arr[i+1]
        var result;

        try {
            if (typeof (num1) == 'string' || typeof (num2) == 'string') {
                throw num1, "or", num2, "is not a number";
            } else if (num2 == 0) {
                throw 'Cant multiply with 0'
            } else {
                result = num1*num2
            }
                
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            result = NaN;

        } finally {
            arr[i] = result
        }
        
    }
    return arr
}

console.log(xNumbers([2,3,4,5]));
// expected output 6, 12, 20 - doesn't work
```

Comment: `lenght` is not how you spell `length` for a start.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Find the first point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what you expect & say what you expect & why you expect it, justified by reference to authoritative documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code.

```js
function xNumbers (arr) {
    arr = arr.map(x => Number(x))
    result = new Array(arr.length -1)
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
        result[i] = arr[i] * arr[i + 1]
    }
    return result
}

console.log(xNumbers([2,3,4,5]));
```

Comment: That's also a very good and short code to do the same exact thing. I am not very into the map function, but trying to learn it. What does the 2nd line of code do in this example?

Comment: @EmilNoer the second line is just converting every element in `arr` to a `number`. `Array.map()` takes a function as an argument and applies it to all the elements of an array, returning a new array with whatever came out from that. i.e. `[1,2].map(x => { return x + 1; })` will give you `[2, 3]`